# Solve this PDE $xu_x+yu_y=u$ with "condition" $x=\cos t, y=\sin t, u=1$ (problem with condition/particular solution)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, differential

Find the particular solution for the part differential equation
$$xu_x+yu_y=u \\ x=\cos t, y=\sin t, u=1$$

It's the first time I've encountered this PDE with this type "condition" (and I don't know how to solve them)

If I solve it in the "normal" way:
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{u}$$
$$\ln|C_1 \cdot x|=\ln|y|$$
$$C_1=\frac{y}{x}$$
And:
$$\int \frac{dx}{x}=\int \frac{du}{u}$$
$$\ln|C_2 \cdot x|=\ln|u|$$
$$C_2=\frac{u}{x}$$
Because:
$$C_2=F(C_1)$$
General solution:
$$u(x,y)=xF\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$

And what next? How do I set the condition correctly?

$$u(x,y)=xF\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) \Rightarrow 1=\cos t \cdot F\left(\frac{\sin t}{\cos t}\right)$$
So:
$$F\left(\frac{\sin t}{\cos t}\right)=\frac{1}{\cos t}$$

What is the particular solution? How to correctly use the conditions given in the task?
Or maybe it needs to be done before solving the general equations? -> How?

Please give me hint/help.

Comment: You need to use the method of characteristics to propagate the values from the unit circle.

Comment: I don't know how and when, we calculate in class only PDE with normally boundary condition. Could you show me (maybe how to start)?

Comment: Alternatively, change to polar coordinates to get $u_r = u$ with boundary condition $u(r,\theta)=1$

Answer (score 1):

You have to write $\frac{1}{\cos t}=\sec t$ as a function of $\frac{\sin t}{\cos t}=\tan t$. That's not difficult:
$$
\sec t=\text{sgn}(\sec t)\sqrt{\sec^2 t}
=\text{sgn}(\sec t)\sqrt{1+\tan^2 t}. \tag{1}
$$
It follows from $(1)$ that
$$
F(\tan t)=\text{sgn}(\sec t)\sqrt{1+\tan^2 t} \implies F\!\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)
=\text{sgn}(x)\sqrt{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}}, \tag{2}
$$
hence
$$
u(x,y)=xF\!\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=x\,\text{sgn}(x)\sqrt{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}}
=|x|\sqrt{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}}=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}. \tag{3}
$$

Comment: How to $xsgn(x)=|x|$? It should not be $\pm \sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}$?

Comment: If $u(x,y)=-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, then $u(\cos t,\sin t)=-1$, instead of $1$.

Comment: Ok, but what is the law that $xsgn(x)=|x|$ I read that $sgn(x)=\frac{x}{|x|}$ for non-zero, so $xsgn(x)=\frac{x^2}{|x|}$? how to get $xsgn(x)=|x|$?

Comment: If $x>0$, then $|x|=x$; if $x<0$, then $|x|=-x$. You obtain the same results using $|x|=x\text{ sgn}(x)$.

Comment: but for $x<0$ and $-x$ we can also write that $$-x\sqrt{\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{x^{2}}}=\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$$?? we can attach -x under square root?

Comment: If $x<0$, then $-x=|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$, so $$-x\sqrt{\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{x^{2}}}=\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{x^2}}=\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}.$$

Comment: Can you help me -> I make approach to second order PDE, but I don't know how to start -> https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4848933/solve-this-pde-u-xxu-0-how-to-start

Answer (score 1):

Another procedure is to explicitly parametrize the characteristics. This yields the system of ODEs

$$\frac{dx}{ds}=x(s),\quad \frac{dy}{ds}=y(s),\quad \frac{du}{ds}=u(x(s),y(s))$$
as the characteristic equations parametrized by $s$ (since $t$ is taken). If we start with a point on the unit circle, i.e., $$x(0)=\cos t,\quad y(0)=\sin t,\quad u(x(0),y(0))=1$$
then the solutions are immediately $$x(s)=e^s \cos t,\quad y(s)=e^s \sin t,\quad u(x(s),y(s))=e^s.$$
Since $$x(s)^2+y(s)^2=e^{2s}\implies e^s=\sqrt{x(s)^2+y(s)^2},$$ we conclude $$u(x(s),y(s))=\sqrt{x(s)^2+y(s)^2}$$
and thus $u(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is the solution.

Comment: This solution method also directly generalizes if the initial data was $u=g(t)$ for some $2\pi$-periodic function of $t$: $u(x,y)=g(t) \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ where $t=\operatorname{atan2}(x,y)$ (using atan2 instead of ordinary atan to avoid ambiguity.)

Comment: Yes I yesterday solve this equation alone in this way :) with $s=ln(sqrt(x^2+y^2)) \Rightarrow u(x,y)=e^{ln(sqrt(x^2+y^2)}=sqrt(x^2+y^2)$

Comment: We can't write only t in our calculation? We need use parametry s?

Comment: @Gregory99 $t$ is already being used to parametrize the initial data $(x,y)=(\cos t,\sin t)$ so it can't be used again to parametrize the characteristic curves. You're free to relabel the former as $(x,y)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ and then use $t$ instead of $s$, but $t$ gets used so often in PDEs that using $s$ instead that I still like to use $s$ instead.